# Laravel - Create automated CRUD?

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-artisan

Is Artisan got a tool for create the code of a CRUD automated in Laravel?
I search information about it but all the options are with an external tool outside of Artisan.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:model Entity -mrc
```

It create a model & migration file & a resource Controller name EntityController.

To create only a resource controller,

```
php artisan make:controller EntityController --resource
```

This command will generate a controller at app/Http/Controllers/EntityController.php

In here you have 7 functions

1.index(to show all data)

2.create(to get the blade file creation)

3.store(to store data into database)

4.show(to show specific data)

5.edit(to get the edit blade file )

6.update(to update that specific data into database)

7.destroy(to delete data)

Next, you may register a resourceful route to the controller:

```
Route::resource('entities', 'EntityController');
```